# My tensorflow code in the process of running, ROM memory continues to increase, eventually leading to memory crashes

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is my code, I tried several ways can not be solved,Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

I've always suspected that I've added a new node in some places, but I can not find the reason. This problem I have never encountered before, I also try to manually clear the memory, but did not succeed. There is a problem, when running this code, my GPU work efficiency only 2%, can improve the efficiency of the GPU?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sklearn.metrics
import copy
import time
import gc


class DataDeal():
    def __init__(self, batch_size):
        self._batch_size = batch_size

    def readTfrecord(self, file, epoch=None, isTrain=True):
        fileQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor=[file], num_epochs=epoch, shuffle=True)
        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, example_series = reader.read(queue=fileQueue)
        features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=example_series,
                                           features={"label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                                     "data_raw": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)})
        data = tf.decode_raw(features["data_raw"], out_type=tf.float32)
        label = tf.decode_raw(features["label"], out_type=tf.int32)
        data = tf.reshape(data, shape=(1, 600))
        label = tf.reshape(label, shape=(1, 2))
        if isTrain:
            data, label = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data, label], batch_size=self._batch_size, capacity=2000,
                                                 min_after_dequeue=500, num_threads=3)
        else:
            assert epoch == None, "wrong!"
            data, label = tf.train.batch([data, label], batch_size=500)
        return (data, label)


class DNN(DataDeal):
    def __init__(self, layer_shape, epoch, eta, batch_size, norm=True, L2_loss=True):
        super(DNN, self).__init__(batch_size)
        self._layer_shape = [600] + layer_shape + [2]
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self._norm = norm
        self.L2_loss = L2_loss
        self.eta = eta
        self.epoch = epoch
        with tf.name_scope("input"):
            self.x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, 600), name="input_X")
            self.y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(None, 2), name="label")
            self.keep_pro = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="keep_pro")
            self._y = tf.cast(self.y, dtype=tf.float32)
        with tf.variable_scope("dnn"):
            self._W = [tf.get_variable(name="layerW_%d" % index, shape=(x[0], x[1]), dtype=tf.float32,
                                       initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
                       for index, x in enumerate(list(zip(self._layer_shape[:-1], self._layer_shape[1:])))]
            self._B = [tf.get_variable(name="layerB_%d" % index, shape=(1, x1), dtype=tf.float32,
                                       initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())
                       for index, x1 in enumerate(self._layer_shape[1:])]
            self.global_step = tf.get_variable(name="global_step", dtype=tf.int32, initializer=0,
                                               trainable=False)  # GLOBAL STEP

    def batch_normalization(self, input_):
        mean, var = tf.nn.moments(input_, [0, 1], keep_dims=True)
        shift = tf.get_variable(shape=[1, input_.get_shape().as_list()[-1]], dtype=tf.float32,
                                initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), name="shift_1")
        scale = tf.get_variable(shape=[1, input_.get_shape().as_list()[-1]], dtype=tf.float32,
                                initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0), name="scale_1")
        # shift= tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1, input_.get_shape().as_list()[-1]],dtype=tf.float32))
        epsilon = 1e-3
        output = tf.nn.batch_normalization(input_, mean, var, shift, scale, epsilon)
        return output

    def run(self):
        first_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.x, self._W[0]), self._B[0])
        if self._norm:
            first_output = tf.nn.relu(self.batch_normalization(input_=first_output))  # relu+BN
        else:
            first_output = tf.nn.sigmoid(first_output)
        for i in range(1, len(self._W) - 1):
            if self._norm:
                first_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(first_output, self._W[i]), self._B[i])
                with tf.variable_scope("layer%d" % i):
                    first_output = tf.nn.relu(self.batch_normalization(input_=first_output))
            else:
                first_output = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(first_output, self._W[i]), self._B[i]))
        first_output = tf.nn.dropout(first_output, keep_prob=self.keep_pro)
        last_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(first_output, self._W[-1]), self._B[-1])
        return last_output


if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_train = "D:/traindata/XIEBO/train.tfrecords"
    file_test = "D:/traindata/XIEBO/test.tfrecords"
    dnn_object = DNN(layer_shape=[512, 128],
                     epoch=5000,
                     eta=0.001,
                     batch_size=128,
                     norm=False,
                     L2_loss=True)
    data, label = dnn_object.readTfrecord(file=file_train, epoch=dnn_object.epoch,
                                          isTrain=True)
    data_test, label_test = dnn_object.readTfrecord(file=file_test, epoch=None, isTrain=False)
    output = tf.nn.softmax(dnn_object.run())
    tvars = copy.copy(tf.trainable_variables())
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=dnn_object.y, logits=output)
    if dnn_object.L2_loss:
        loss_l2 = 0.0005 * tf.reduce_sum([tf.nn.l2_loss(x) for x in tvars])
        loss += loss_l2
    train_first_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=dnn_object.eta).minimize(loss=loss,
                                                                                              global_step=dnn_object.global_step)
    variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.999, num_updates=dnn_object.global_step)
    variable_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_first_op]):
        train_step = tf.group(variable_averages_op)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # sess.graph.finalize()
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        data_test, label_test = sess.run([data_test, label_test])
        data_test = np.reshape(data_test, newshape=(-1, 600))
        label_test = np.reshape(label_test, newshape=(-1, 2))
        step = 0
        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                data_batch, label_batch = sess.run([data, label])
                data_batch = np.reshape(data_batch, newshape=(-1, 600))
                label_batch = np.reshape(label_batch, newshape=(-1, 2))
                _, pred_label, loss_look = sess.run([train_step, output, tf.reduce_mean(loss)], feed_dict={
                    dnn_object.x: data_batch, dnn_object.y: label_batch, dnn_object.keep_pro: 0.8})
                if (step != 0) & (step % 100 == 0):
                    print("now is step %d, trainning acc is %s, trainning loss is %s" % (
                        step, np.mean(np.equal(np.argmax(pred_label, axis=1), np.argmax(label_batch, axis=1))),
                        loss_look
                    ))
                    del data_batch, label_batch, pred_label, loss_look
                    gc.collect()
                    pred_label, loss_look = sess.run([output, tf.reduce_mean(loss)], feed_dict={
                        dnn_object.x: data_test, dnn_object.y: label_test, dnn_object.keep_pro: 1.0})
                    print("now is step %d, testing acc is %s, testing loss is %s" % (
                        step, np.mean(np.equal(np.argmax(pred_label, axis=1), np.argmax(label_test, axis=1))),
                        loss_look
                    ))
                    del pred_label, loss_look
                    gc.collect()
                    print(step, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
                else:
                    del data_batch, label_batch, pred_label, loss_look
                    gc.collect()
                step += 1
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as e:
            print(e, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads=threads)
            print("over", time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(time.time())))
```

Answer (score 0):

i just solve this problem.The reason is i use this code:

```
 _, pred_label, loss_look = sess.run([train_step, output, tf.reduce_mean(loss)], feed_dict={dnn_object.x: data_batch, dnn_object.y: label_batch, dnn_object.keep_pro: 0.8})\
```

and the tf.reduce_mean(loss) has built a new Variable or Opt every loop when i am training my model.
and now i want to know how can i improve my GPU efficiency? or maybe it is Can not be artificially improved.